# Select entries from matrix based on row number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, select, matrix

I have matrix `A=rand(M,N)` and row vector `B=randi([1 M],1,N)`. I want to assign entries to `C` from `A` according to the row numbers in `B`. That is
`C(1,1)=A(B(1,1),1)`,  `C(1,2)=A(B(1,2),2)`, etc. Is there easier way to get `C` without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert row subscripts, `B`, and column subscripts, `1:numel(B)`, into linear indices

```
C = A(sub2ind(size(A), B, 1:numel(B)));
```